# Stroke left and right side of rect svg

Tags: html, svg, d3.js

I have drawn a rect in svg using d3 and would like to stroke only the left and right side.

```html
<rect class="extent" x="578" width="356" height="250"
      style="cursor: move; opacity: 0.2; fill: #FF9000;" ></rect>
```

Comment: Here's another SO question that has suggests a hack to do this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8976791/how-to-set-a-stroke-width1-on-only-certain-sides-of-svg-shapes

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set a stroke-width:1 on only certain sides of SVG shapes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8976791/how-to-set-a-stroke-width1-on-only-certain-sides-of-svg-shapes)

Comment: You can just add `.attr("stroke-dasharray", [0, rectWidth, rectHeight, 0] )` to your rectangle and replace `rectWidth` and `rectHeight` with your values or variables. See the @Jonah comment above or the @tripathy answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/59773921

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's another hack, but you can add a filter to your shape and clip the top and bottom by your strokewidth - which here I'm assuming is 1 unit.

```html
<defs>
   <filter id="clippy" x="0" y="1" height="248" width="356">
     <feColorMatrix type="identity"/>
   </filter>
</defs>
<rect filter="url(#clippy)" class="extent" width="356" height="250"
      style="cursor: move;opacity: 0.2; fill: #FF9000;" x="578"></rect>
```

**Update:**

Here is the d3.js version of the answer created by Christopher Chiche (see original lower down):

```js
svg.append("defs").append("filter")
    .attr("id", "clippy")
    .attr("x", "0")
    .attr("y", "1")
    .attr("height", "248")
    .attr("width" "356")
    .append("feColorMatrix")
    .attr("type", "identity")

svg.append("rect")
    .attr("filter", "url(#clippy)")
    .attr("class", "extent") 
    .attr("style", "cursor:move; opacity:0.2; fill: #FF9000")
    .attr("x", "578")
    .attr("height", "250")
    .attr("width" "356")
```

Edit:

Really, The best answer is probably to use the stroke-dasharray method - linked in the question comment above, rather than mess with filters.

Comment: agree with @ChrisJamesC could you do that?

Comment: @Jonah references an absolutely brilliant solution using `stroke-dasharray`

Answer (score 4):

Here is the `d3.js` version of the answer posted by Michael Mullany. I just did this as an exercise to have fun:

```
svg.append("defs").append("filter")
    .attr("id", "clippy")
    .attr("x", "0")
    .attr("y", "1")
    .attr("height", "248")
    .attr("width" "356")
    .append("feColorMatrix")
    .attr("type", "identity")

svg.append("rect")
    .attr("filter", "url(#clippy)")
    .attr("class", "extent") 
    .attr("style", "cursor:move; opacity:0.2; fill: #FF9000")
    .attr("x", "578")
    .attr("height", "250")
    .attr("width" "356")
```

Comment: Hi Chris - if you're ok with it, I can cut and paste this into my answer and credit you. B

Comment: hey, should that "deColorMatrix" be "feColorMatrix", or is that a d3 thing?

Comment: As you stated it should be "deColorMatrix"

Answer (score 3):

[Codepen] (https://codepen.io/shaswatatripathy/pen/oNgPpyd)

HTML

```
    <rect x="0.5" y="0.5" width="50" height="50" class="topBottom"/>


    <rect x="70.5" y="0.5" width="50" height="50" class="left"/>
    <rect x="140.5" y="0.5" width="50" height="50" class="topRight"/>
    <rect x="200.5" y="0.5" width="50" height="50" class="top"/>
  <rect x="260.5" y="0.5" width="50" height="50" class="bottomLeft"/>
  <rect x="320.5" y="0.5" width="50" height="50" class="bottomRight"/>

  <rect x="380.5" y="0.5" width="50" height="50" class="topLeft"/>

   <rect x="440.5" y="0.5" width="50" height="50" class="right"/>
  <rect x="500.5" y="0.5" width="50" height="50" class="bottom"/>

  <rect x="560.5" y="0.5" width="50" height="50" class="leftRight"/>

</svg>
```

CSS

```
rect { fill: none; stroke: black; }
.topBottom { stroke-dasharray: 50 }
.leftRight { stroke-dasharray: 0,50,50,0 }

.bottomLeft { stroke-dasharray: 0,100,150 }
.bottomRight { stroke-dasharray: 0,50,50 }
.topRight { stroke-dasharray: 100 }
.topLeft { stroke-dasharray: 50,100 }

.left { stroke-dasharray: 0,150,50 }
.top { stroke-dasharray: 50,150 }
.bottom { stroke-dasharray: 0,100,50,100 }
.right { stroke-dasharray: 0,50, 50,50 }
```

Answer (score 0):

My example was when using d3.js and the brush tool.

```
# Brush object
brush.x(core.xScale()).on("brush", onBrush)         

# Call the brush object
container.call(brush).selectAll("rect").attr("height", core.height())

# Method on brush
onBrush = () ->
  extent = brush.extent()
  extent = if brush.empty() then core.xScale().domain() else extent
```

Anyway, as part of the brush tool, 2 rectangles are added as left and right bounds to the brush. You can simply select these using css and restyle them. This is what I ended up doing and here is my solution in .less

```
.resize {
    rect { 
        visibility: visible !important;
        fill: #444444;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't seem to do that.

You probably need to draw a line on both sides and subtract those line-widths from the rect's current width.

Comment: This is not true. See the __Jonah__ comment above or the @tripathy answer stackoverflow.com/a/59773921