# How to add a border on 1 or 2 sides, top, bottom, left, right of a rectangle

Tags: javascript, css, svg

Good day.

I'm not new in javascript and CSS, but I'm also not to good with SVG.

I've been battling with this issue.

I would like to know can you add borders to only one side of a rectangle. 
e.g. Just the bottom or just the left.

I've been to these links while searching but not helping much.

[Stroke left and right side of rect svg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16071515/stroke-left-and-right-side-of-rect-svg)

[How to set a stroke-width:1 on only certain sides of SVG shapes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8976791/how-to-set-a-stroke-width1-on-only-certain-sides-of-svg-shapes)

Thank you advance.

(",)

**EDIT:**

I hope this will be more clear to your understanding.

```
<g id="fdtElem307Group" fdtUngroupable="fdtUngroupable" fdtSelectable="fdtSelectable" fdtType="cursiveNotes" fdtTypeFormat="Converted" fdtFormatOptions="1" fdtFormat="Cursive" fdtTabIndex="24" fdtFieldName="Notes18" fdtResizable="fdtResizable" fdtfont-size="12" fdtRows="4">
<rect id="fdtElem303" fill="#ffffff" stroke="#000000" stroke-dasharray="5,2" stroke-width="1" x="114" y="968" width="240" height="24" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" fdtSelectable="fdtSelectable" fdtActualHeight="25" fdtActualWidth="241" fdtActualY="967" fdtActualX="113"></rect>
<rect id="fdtElem304" fill="#ffffff" stroke="#000000" stroke-dasharray="5,2" stroke-width="1" x="114" y="992" width="240" height="24" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" fdtSelectable="fdtSelectable" fdtActualHeight="25" fdtActualWidth="241" fdtActualY="991" fdtActualX="113"></rect>
<rect id="fdtElem305" fill="#ffffff" stroke="#000000" stroke-dasharray="5,2" stroke-width="1" x="114" y="1016" width="240" height="24" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" fdtSelectable="fdtSelectable" fdtActualHeight="25" fdtActualWidth="241" fdtActualY="1015" fdtActualX="113"></rect>
<rect id="fdtElem306" fill="#ffffff" stroke="#000000" stroke-dasharray="5,2" stroke-width="1" x="114" y="1040" width="240" height="24" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" fdtSelectable="fdtSelectable" fdtActualHeight="25" fdtActualWidth="241" fdtActualY="1039" fdtActualX="113"></rect>
</g>
```

Comment: If you're asking simple border for specific side then use `border-width: 0 0 1px 1px; border-style: solid; border-color: #000;`, where in `border-width` sequence goes like *top* *right* *bottom* *left*.

Comment: There is no `border-width` in svg @vivekkupadhyay

Comment: thats why I wrote *simple border for specific side*

Answer (score 4):

You can use `stroke-dasharray` it's a bit of hack but it will work

Stroke on left -

```html
<svg width="500" height="500">
<rect x="10" y="10" fill="orange" width="200" height="100" stroke-dasharray = "100 1000" stroke = "black" stroke-width="5" stroke-dashoffset ="-500"/></svg>
</svg>
```

Stroke on bottom

```html
<svg width="500" height="500">
<rect x="10" y="10" fill="orange" width="200" height="100" stroke-dasharray = "200 1000" stroke = "black" stroke-width="5" stroke-dashoffset ="-300"/></svg>
</svg>
```

Comment: I've just added a segment of my code.
I hope this will be helpful.

Comment: Clever trick but maybe not the best for responsiveness.

Comment: @MarsAndBack not sure about this but responsiveness maybe achieved by setting a proper viewbox.