# Partial border/stroke using SVG

Tags: javascript, html, svg, d3.js, stroke

I'm using svg/d3 for creating a chart made of 'rect' elements.

What is the best way for adding a partical border/stroke for each rectangle (only on top of the rectangle)?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean something like the dasharray property?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set a stroke-width:1 on only certain sides of SVG shapes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8976791/how-to-set-a-stroke-width1-on-only-certain-sides-of-svg-shapes)

Answer (score 9):

I don't think SVG supports stroking only portions of a rectangle or path - stroke isn't like a CSS border. You're left with a few other options, all of which take some extra work:

- Stroke the entire `rect` and apply a [clipPath](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/masking.html#ClippingPaths) to remove the other three edges - probably works best if you make the rectangles bigger than necessary.
- Apply a [linear gradient](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/pservers.html#LinearGradients) fill to each rect, using the gradient definition to show a "border" at the top of the shape.
- Add a separate `line` element to act as the border for each `rect`.
- Use the `stroke-dasharray` property ([docs](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/painting.html#StrokeProperties)) to set a dash definition where the "dash" only covers the top of the `rect`. This might be tricky to get right, but I suspect it wouldn't be too hard, as the stroke probably begins at the top left of the shape.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go with stroke, then use [stroke-dasharray](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/stroke-dasharray). The simplest way to use it is with two numbers: `stroke-dasharray = "length-of-dash, length-of-gap"`. These lengths can either be in the raw units of your SVG parent element (as defined in `viewBox`) or as a [percentage of the normalized diagonal of the viewBox-defined area or the SVG parent element](https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/painting.html#StrokeDashing): `Math.sqrt((width ** 2) + (height ** 2)) / Math.sqrt(2)`.

So, if your rectangles and SVG are of a fixed size and you know exactly how big your `<rect>`s will be, you can use `stroke-dasharray = "width, perimeter - width"`. That's basically saying that your dash will be as long as your `<rect>` is wide, and the dash gap will be as long as the length of the rest of the sides. The dash starts at the top-left corner and goes around the `<rect>` clockwise, so this works out perfect for your use case.

On the other hand, if your table will be responsive, you'll have to do some math to make the percentages work.

Let's say `fullDash = perimeter / normalizedDiagonal * 100`; that will be the percentage value that equates to a dash as long as the perimeter of your `<rect>`.

`topDash = width / perimeter` is the fraction of the perimeter we want to cover.

Now we can say that we want our dash to be `dash = topDash * fullDash` and our gap to be at least `fullDash` (but we could be exact if we wanted and call it `gap = fullDash - dash`) so our final dasharray will look something like `stroke-dasharray = "${dash}%, ${fullDash}%"`.

You can see a rough sketch of this here: https://dkallen78.github.io/math-trainer/experiments/dasharray-test.html