# Highcharts bar border

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a columnrange chart, but I think the answer (if there is one) will be applicable to any of the bar/column chart types.

Working fiddle >> http://jsfiddle.net/lunchboxbill/8Yvfs/10/

I have a nice fat border around the first bar. Is there a way I can set it so that the border only displays on the left hand side?

A CSS Highcharts equivalent of "border-left" if you like.

```
borderLeft: 10
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In general, in SVG it's not possible to apply border only for a part of rect. It would require to draw another path for it, just like [that SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8976791/how-to-set-a-stroke-width1-on-only-certain-sides-of-svg-shapes) question.

And, as you can see in API, only `borderWidth` is possible to set: [docs](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.columnrange.borderWidth).