# Highchart Rectangle Border Radius

Tags: highcharts

I have an highchart rectangle on a chart. Is it possible to set only the borders on the right to have radius and sharp corners for the left?

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/members/renderer-rect/

I have tried to set the borderRadius (hyphenated) in .CSS as well, but that didn't work too.

```
renderer.rect(100, 100, 100, 100, 0)
        .attr({
            'stroke-width': 2,
            stroke: 'red',
            fill: 'yellow',
            zIndex: 3
        })
        .css({
        borderRadius:'10px'
        })
        .add();
```

Thanks!

Comment: Highcharts are using SVG elements. It's not directly supported, see [that question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8976791/how-to-set-a-stroke-width1-on-only-certain-sides-of-svg-shapes).

Answer (score 2):

It seems this isn't possibly (easily) as highcharts will render it as SVG element which can't be altered preferentially. Thanks Pawel Fus.