# c3js d3 dash-stroke only one side of rect element

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

i have a rect element and i want to set up a dash stroke only in the right side, currently i've added the lines with css like this:

```
.c3-event-rect {
  stroke: #ccc;
  stroke-dasharray: 1,3;
  stroke-width: 1px;
}
```

with javascritp is something like

```
d3.selectAll('.c3-event-rect')
          .style('stroke-dasharray', ('2,3'))
          .style('stroke', '#dedede')
```

but the dashed is covered all the sides 
i've tried this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8976791/how-to-set-a-stroke-width1-on-only-certain-sides-of-svg-shapes) but i don't get the result that i want

Comment: Include what you tried based on the other post and describe why that isn't what you want.

Comment: basically i want to set the same typo of lines that the post, but the post the lines are solid, and i want a dashed line in one side only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to break up the 50 which forms the space into smaller dashes. Something like this perhaps.

```css
rect { fill: none; stroke: black; }
.right { stroke-dasharray: 50,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,100 }
```

```html
<svg height="300">
<rect x="0.5" y="0.5" width="50" height="50" class="right"/>
</svg>
```

or if you only want 1 side dashed add a zero at the beginning so the solid and dashed areas swap.

```css
rect { fill: none; stroke: black; }
.right { stroke-dasharray: 0,50,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,100 }
```

```html
<svg height="300">
<rect x="0.5" y="0.5" width="50" height="50" class="right"/>
</svg>
```

Alternatively draw the shape as 2 paths, one which is the solid 3 sided shape and the other which is a vertical dashed line.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve your expected result, use dashed line to the right of rectangle

```
var svgContainer = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", 200)
  .attr("height", 200);

//Draw the Rectangle
var rectangle = svgContainer.append("rect")
  .attr("x", 10)
  .attr("y", 10)
  .attr("width", 50)
  .attr("height", 100);

svgContainer.append("line") 
  .style("stroke", "black") 
  .attr("x1", 60) 
  .attr("y1", 10) 
  .attr("x2", 60) 
  .attr("y2", 110)
  .style("stroke-dasharray", ("2, 3"))
```

http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/zBREmV