# CSS - can we add different colors as borders for an svg polygon?

Tags: html, css, polygon

HTML

```
<svg class="triangle">
    <polygon  class="my_polygon" style="" points="9 0, 0 9, 9 18" fill="#FFFFF"/>
  </svg>
```

CSS

```
.my_polygon {
 width: 20vw;
  height: 20vw;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  stroke: red;
  fill: red;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

This gives us something like this : [image]

Now if I wish to change the border color (in our case stroke) of only one side of the triangle say , is there a way to do that ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8976791/how-to-set-a-stroke-width1-on-only-certain-sides-of-svg-shapes