# Add border to an svg

Tags: html, css, svg

I have an SVG used as a divider and I was wondering if on the curve of the svg, I can add a blue or black border that follows the path of the curve.

```html
<svg width="100%" height="96px" viewBox="0 0 100 100" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" preserveAspectRatio="none">
           <path fill="#f4f6ff" d="M0,0 C40,33 66,52 75,52 C83,52 92,33 100,0 L100,100 L0,100 L0,0 Z"></path>
     </svg>
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8976791/how-to-set-a-stroke-width1-on-only-certain-sides-of-svg-shapes

Comment: Only if you duplicate that part of the border. Otherwise a border will be applied to the entire shape.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure - just draw a path with a stroke on top of the shape.

```html
<svg width="100%" height="96px" viewBox="0 0 100 100" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" preserveAspectRatio="none">
           <path fill="#f4f6ff" d="M0,0 C40,33 66,52 75,52 C83,52 92,33 100,0 L100,100 L0,100 L0,0 Z"></path>
                      <path fill="none" stroke="grey" stroke-width="1px" d="M0,0 C40,33 66,52 75,52 C83,52 92,33 100,0"></path>
     </svg>
```

You can also stroke the original path and use a stroke-dasharray of the appropriate construction to make the dash cover just the top of the shape. Or you can use a svg filter to add a border to the top edge. Just drawing the border explicitly is the most straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the CSS `filter` property if you can't directly edit the SVG to add the path (which might be a better way to go).

```css
svg path {
  filter: drop-shadow(0 -2px 0 blue);
}
```

```html
<svg class="curve" width="100%" height="96px" viewBox="0 0 100 100" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" preserveAspectRatio="none">
           <path fill="#f4f6ff" d="M0,0 C40,33 66,52 75,52 C83,52 92,33 100,0 L100,100 L0,100 L0,0 Z"></path>
     </svg>
```