# How to remove top border from svg stroke

Tags: html, css, border

i created dashed border with some generator in the net,
i trying to remove the top border but with no luck.

```css
div {
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg width='100%25' height='100%25' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3e%3crect width='100%25' height='100%25' fill='none' stroke='%23D8D8D8' stroke-width='2' stroke-dasharray='10%2c 18' stroke-dashoffset='0' stroke-linecap='square'/%3e%3c/svg%3e");
    width: 100%;
  min-height:400px;
    border-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

i know that i need to change something in stroke-dasharray but dont know what,
tnx for your help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set a stroke-width:1 on only certain sides of SVG shapes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8976791/how-to-set-a-stroke-width1-on-only-certain-sides-of-svg-shapes)

Comment: @ATP no, because its static by pixels i have responsive box without specific width and height

Comment: `border-top` doesn't work because SVG's don't use borders, they use strokes. The only thing you can do about it is either putting something over it or placing the SVG partially out of view..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your border is not actually CSS `border` but `background`, you might use `background-position` to shift the top "border" out of the view,  and `background-size` to compensate the shift:

(I changed stroke color and added outline for better visualization)

```css
div {
    background: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg width='100%25' height='100%25' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3e%3crect width='100%25' height='100%25' fill='none' stroke='%23000' stroke-width='2' stroke-dasharray='10%2c 18' stroke-dashoffset='0' stroke-linecap='square'/%3e%3c/svg%3e")
    no-repeat
    0 -2px / 100% calc(100% + 2px);
    
    width: 100%;
  min-height:400px;
    border-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    
    outline:solid 1px #f005;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```